# Get all selected values of all select menus and output values in an unordered list

Tags: javascript

I have **multiple** select drowdowns on my page, and I have put the **same** onchange function to all the select menus like so:

```
<select onchange="myResultsFunction()">
  <option></option>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Whenever the selected value of **any** of the select dropdowns change, then it must display an updated list of values in a specific div like so:

```
<div id="selected-results">
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So, I need some help with the actual function, because I don't know how to go from here. My function starts off by getting the ID of the div where I want the unordered list of results to show. But how do I go from here? Because I assume I need to output it using a loop or something in order for me to create a list of results? And how do I actually grab the selected value in the dropdowns?

```
function myResultsFunction() {
document.getElementByID("selected-results");
}
```

Comment: I'd add a class to all your select to select them all and map through them to get their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select.custom_component_option_select");
// get all selelct elements with class  .custom_component_option_select


var list = document.querySelector("#selected-results > ul");
//get list, ul element

selects.forEach(select => {
//for each select element
  select.addEventListener('change', event => {
  // add event Listener change
    myResultsFunction()
    // on change call function
  })
})


function myResultsFunction() {
  list.innerHTML = "";
// on change empty the list 
  selects.forEach(select => {
// for each select 

    if ((select.options[select.selectedIndex].text !== "...") === true) {
    // if selcted value is not ... , feel free to edit his
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      // creat new li
      li.innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
      // add value to it
      list.appendChild(li);
      // add to list
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<select class="custom_component_option_select">
  <option selected value="test">...</option>
  <option value="test">1-1</option>
  <option value="test">1-2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_component_option_select">
  <option selected value="test">...</option>
  <option value="test">2-1</option>
  <option value="test">2-2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_component_option_select">
  <option selected>...</option>
  <option value="test">3-1</option>
  <option value="test">3-2</option>
</select>


<div id="selected-results">
  <ul>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't seem to work. I don't know if i'm doing it wrong. Am I not supposed to use a loop or something?

Comment: @Shtarley You have working solution in front of you. It does work like I made it. And you do not need loops for anything. It can be done with looping thure all select elements values and mapping them, and creating every time new list from start. This is simpler and easy way the way I did it.  You have working solution snippet in front of you, with full explanation how it works in description.

Comment: @Shtarley Take a good look at snippet, compare it with your code. Check your console.log for java-script errors. "doesn't seem to work" means nothing to me i'm afraid. It works as you see it on front of you. You need to give me something to work on, some error, or full production code to compare it...

Comment: I got it to work. Thanx for your help, sorry I was being stupid. The only issue I have now, is that when someone changes the value of the select dropdown for a second time, then it will output a second li tag instead of updating the current one. So, if someone changes the select value 5 times, then it will create a new li tag each time. I only want the last selected value for each select dropdown to be in the list. So that they can basically see a summary of their selection based on each dropdown.

Comment: @Shtarley That was not mentioned at all, I will update the function now. How many selects you have? and do they have some ids, classes?

Comment: Thank you, sorry, I didn't originally realize that it would be necessary. I don't have a set number of selects. The select boxes depends on the settings for each page (it is displayed with a php loop). So I need something that are not dependent on a set number of selects. They all have the same class, but no ID.

Comment: @Shtarley What is the class? And yes, we will make a loop in this case...

Comment: The class name is "custom_component_option_select". Your help is sooooo appreciated.

Comment: @Shtarley I changed a code a bit, and added comments to it, I'm in hurry now to get out, but all should be clear from comments in code. Live me a massage, can i adjust it later, cheers.

Comment: Wow, you are amazing. Thank you, and you are my Code-Hero for the day. Thanx a million. It looks like it will work just fine, but thank you, I will message you if I have any questions.

Comment: Your code works great, I just realised that the code I want to use this with does not put the title in the "value" but the ID.  My option tags looks like this: 
<option value="39048">Component Title</option> Is it possible to grap the actual text of the selected item instead of the value? By the way, if it helps, I will be able to add a label attribute like so: <option label="Component Title" value="39048">Component Title</option> in case it will make things any easier.

Comment: @Shtarley That is not a problem, sure you can target just text, you don't have to change anything, just target `.options[select.selectedIndex].text` insted of `.value`, I updated the fiddle.